# How to find an attribute's largest value based on another attribute?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, psql

```
Owner | Price
-------------
James | 8000
David | 1500
James | 20000
Kim   | 4500
Kim   | 9500
```

For example if I have the above table displaying the owner's name of some watches and their price. How could I find out the most expensive watch each person has? So the result table should have 3 tuples in that case.

Comment: It's the most basic case of `GROUP BY` imaginable and should be covered by the first page of any manual. Like: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` and MAX can get you what you want.

```
select Owner, MAX(price) as maxPrice
FROM Table1
Group by Owner
```

Comment: what if I dont want to display price in my result table?

Comment: @user3300198, can you writ your expected output then